# Prefix search against half a billion strings

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search, data-structures

I have a list of 500 mil strings. The strings are alphanumeric, ASCII characters, of varying size (usually from 2-30 characters). Also, they're single words (or a combination of words without spaces like 'helloiamastring').

What I need is a fast way to check against a target, say 'hi'. The result should be all strings from the 500mil list which start with 'hi' (for eg. 'hithere', 'hihowareyou' etc.). This needs to be fast because there will be a new query each time the user types something, so if he types "hi", all strings starting with "hi" from the 500 mil list will be shown, if he types "hey", all strings starting with "hey" will show etc.

I've tried with the Tries algo, but the memory footprint to store 300 mil strings is just huge. It should require me 100GB+ ram for that. And I'm pretty sure the list will grow up to a billion.

What is a fast algorithm for this use case?

P.S. In case there's no fast option, the best alternative would be to limit people to enter at least, say, 4 characters, before results show up. Is there a fast way to retrieve the results then?

Comment: Why don't you use a database ([Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) can run in memory, if you absolutely want to keep your data in memory)?

Comment: `[Trie] memory footprint to store 300 mil strings is just huge [100GB+]` How did you implement the Trie? What language/run-time environment? Contemporary ones tend to support 16 bit unicode. (I support J. Coleman's idea of using O(1) lookup for the first eg. 2 characters.) _Stemming_ should reduce the memory footprint of regular dictionaries; I expect the advantage smaller in your case.

Comment: `there will be a new query each time the user types something` is there going to be an indication of _done typing_? If not, once the user has somehow benefited from all the results after typing the first two characters of _hi_ deous, the next search (_hid_) need not start from scratch.

Comment: @greybeard it was a rought estimate, but still even with the most efficient algo, I guess it wouldn't take less than 30GB, and considering the nature of the problem that these long strings will grow, well, any type of in-memory structure is not a good idea (unless there's some extremely efficient algo for prefix matching in terms of size I'm not aware of).

Comment: The biggest obstacle I see is something almost entirely unrelated to representing and searching _the string set_: How are you going to _represent and use the results_? Even with case distinction, we are talking a few thousand possible digraphs, about 100´000 hits _on average_, with popular ones (like consonant followed by vowel) _much_ higher.

Comment: I take it for granted that _the strings_ will not be held by the device (sans "mass storage peripherals") the user operates: what will be the connection? Can you provide access to (and a description of) a significant sample string set?

Comment: @greybeard the string set is a list of all registered .com TLDs. Basically, they're all different length etc, imagine "stackoverflow.com" as being 1 sample. So when you enter "stack" it should show you all .coms starting with "stack". So the data will be on the computer, it is a text file which is several gigs in size. And as far as I could see, that list is alphabetically sorted.

Comment: At the beginning of 2017, there were about 1500 top-level domains, with about 126 million registered domains in `.com`. You _may_ be thinking of _all registered_ domains - about 200 (oops) millions.

Comment: @greybeard yeah, but still in the hundreds of millions and growing, you get the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure Python is the best language for this task

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `not sure Python is the best language for [string/char banging]` - as in _Python has a ~26 byte overhead per string_ (and a char is a string of length 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [Directed Acyclic Word Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) or DAWG.  This generalizes @greybeard's suggestion to use stemming.

See, for example, the discussion in section 3.2 of [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s06/www/lectures/scrabble.pdf).

Comment: Is there some library in any programming language for this?

Comment: There is a [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DAWG/0.7.1) implementing the DAWG.  If this doesn't handle the size of your data set, the author of that package claims that the [marisa-trie](https://github.com/pytries/marisa-trie) works for larger data sets, although it is slower.

Comment: I see, it would be nice if there was something for Ruby as well. I saw a C# version.

Answer (score 3):

If the strings are sorted then a binary search is reasonable. As a speedup, you could maintain a dictionary of all possible bigrams ("aa", "ab", etc.) where the corresponding values are the first and last index starting with that bigram (if any do) and so in `O(1)` time zero in on a much smaller sublist that contains the strings that you are looking for. Once you find a match, do a linear search to the right and left to get all other matches.

Comment: The strings are not sorted. Considering the list changes every day I don't know if doing a sort of 300 mil records would be a viable solution.

Comment: @anemaria20 I'd guess _in-memory_ "sorting"/categorising time a non-issue, rebuilds as well as updates.

Comment: @anemaria20 If you're keen on speed, sorting will improve your situation by miles. It may take time for *one* initial sort, but as the list grows it should be fairly trivial to just insert things where they belong (assuming you're using the right data structure).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the user to digit at least 4 letters, for example, you can keep a key-value map, memory or disk, where the keys are all combinations of 4 letters (they are not too many if it is case insensitive, otherwise you can limit to three), and the values are list of positions of all strings that begin with the combination.

After the user has typed the three (or four) letters you have at once all the possible strings. From this point on you just loop on this subset.

On average this subset is small enough, i.e. 500M divided by 26^4...just as example. Actually bigger because probably not all sets of 4 letters can be prefix for your strings.

Forgot to say: when you add a new string to the big list, you also update the list of indexes corresponding to the key in the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to use some database, you should create some data related routines pre-existing in all database engines:

1. Doesn't try to load all data in memory.
2. Use fixed length for all string. It increase storage memory consumption but significantly decrease seeking time (i-th string can be found at position L*i bytes in file, where L - fixed length). Create additional mechanism to work with extremely long strings: store it in different place and use special pointers.
3. Sort all of strings. You can use merge sort to do it without load all strings in memory in one time.
4. Create indexes (address of first line starts with 'a','b',... ) also indexes can be created for 2-grams, 3-grams, etc. Indexes can be placed in memory to increase search speed.
5. Use advanced strategies to avoid full indexes regeneration on data update: split a data to a number of files by first letters and update only affected indexes, create an empty spaces in data to decrease affect of read-modify-write procedures, create a cache for a new lines before they will be added to main storage and search in this cache.
6. Use query cache to fast processing a popular requests.

Answer (score 0):

In this hypothetical, where the strings being indexed are not associated with any other information (e.g. other columns in the same row), there is relatively little difference between a complete index and keeping the strings sorted in the first place (as in, some difference, but not as much as you are hoping for).  In light of the growing nature of the list and the cost of updating it, perhaps the opposite approach will better accomplish the performance tradeoffs that you are looking for.

For any given character at any given location in the string, your base case is that no string exists containing that letter.  For example, once 'hello' has been typed, if the next letter typed is 't', then your base case is that there is no string beginning 'hellot'.  There is a finite number of characters that could follow 'hello' at location 5 (say, 26).  You need 26 fixed-length spaces in which to store information about characters that follow 'hello' at location 5.  Each space either says zero if there is no string in which, e.g., 't' follows 'hello', or contains a number of data-storage addresses by which to advance to find the list of characters for which one or more strings involve that character following 'hellot' at location 6 (or use absolute data-storage addresses, although only relative addressess allow the algorithm I propose to support an infinite number of strings of infinite length without any modification to allow for larger pointers as the list grows).

The algorithm can then move forward through this data stored on disk, building a tree of string-beginnings in memory as it goes, and avoiding delays caused by random-access reads.  For an in-memory index, simply store the part of the tree closest to the root in memory.  After the user has typed 'hello' and the algorithm has tracked that information about one or more strings beginning 'hellot' exists at data-storage address X, the algorithm finds one of two types of lists at location X.  Either it is another sequence of, e.g., 26 fixed-length spaces with information about characters following 'hellot' at location 6, or it is a pre-allocated block of space listing all post-fixes that follow 'hellot', depending on how many such post-fixes exist.  Once there are enough post-fixes that using some traditional search and/or sort algorithm to both update and search the post-fix list fails to provide the performance benefits that you desire, it gets divided up and replaced with a sequence of, e.g., 26 fixed-length spaces.

This involves pre-allocating a relatively substantial amount of disk-storage upfront, with the tradeoff that your tree can be maintained in sorted form without needing to move anything around for most updates, and your searches can be peformed *in full* in a *single sequential read*.  It also provides more flexibility and probably requires less storage space than a solution based on storing the strings themselves as fixed-length strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say that the tag you should have added for your question is "Information Retrieval".

I think using [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org)'s [PrefixQuery](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_prefixquery.htm) is the best way you can handle wildcard queries. Apache has a [Python version](https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/index.html) if you are comfortable with python. But to use Apache lucent to solve your problem you should first know about [indexing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_indexing_process.htm) your data(which is the part that your data will be compressed and saved in a more efficient manner).

Also looking to indexing and wildcard query section of [IR book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/irbook.html) will give you a better vision.

Comment: Is this similar to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html

Comment: Elasticsearch and apache solr are search engines based on apache lucene.